# Strange Behavior: Why is container height changed by bootstrap columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See this plnkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/wun8TRdaJoaJTCC4DJ0Q

```
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>
                should be green
            </h1>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          should be green, why am I blue?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mask">
        should be blue
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you used any column class like (col-xs-12 or col-md-6 or any thing) at that time you have to enclose that class with `<div class="row"></div>`. This will clear your float. And this is the framework of Bootstrap. You have to start with "row" class everytime you used "col-*" class.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>
                should be green
          </h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="">
             should be green, why am I blue?
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mask">
      should be blue
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```